# listen to phonegap background event in angular controller

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, angular-routing

I have a phonegap app and want to know when the app goes to background using `pause` (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.6.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#pause) event.
`document.addEventListener("pause",`**yourCallbackFunction**`, false);`
However, I am looking for a way to make **yourCallbackFunction** trigger the **$scope.cancel** when the current route is `/orders` in the current scope and ignore otherwise. How can I achieve this? Appreciate any help.

Note: Device ready had already been fired by the time I come to this page in the application, so not needed to handle the deviceReady.

Code in context here:

html:

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div ng-view=""></div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

javascript in app.js:

```
angular.module('myapp', [ 'ngRoute' ])
  .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', { templateUrl: 'login/login.html', controller: 'LoginCtrl' })
      .when('/orders', { templateUrl: 'app/orders/orders.html', controller: 'OrdersCtrl' });
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
  }]);

app.controller('OrdersCtrl', [ '$scope','$filter','$timeout', function($scope,$filter,$timeout,) {

  $scope.date = new Date();
  $scope.refresh = function(){
      getOrders(); //Implemented elsewhere
  }
  $scope.cancel = function(){
      cancelRefresh(); //Implemented elsewhere
  }

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the pause event when `OrdersCtrl` loads and unsubsribe on scope `$destroy`, so you know the event fires when you're in the correct controller:

```
app.controller('OrdersCtrl'...) {
    function onPause() {
      cancelRefresh();
    }
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        document.removeEventListener("pause", onPause);
    });
});
```

This though only worked for me when I used `ngRoute` and not with `ui-router`.
So another solution can be to add a `run` section to your module, injecting to it `$location` to check the path, and either use a service which can cancel the refresh itself or delegate the work to the controller with a `$broadcast`:

```
app.run(function($location, $rootScope, orderService) {        
    document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
        if ($location.path() === '/orders') {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('pauseEvent');
            orderService.cancel();
        }
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Is there anyway to keep these functions outside the controller or angular? Keeping them inside couples the code and I am trying to keep the code separate..